# Run docker inside Azure Devops using Docker@2 and `start` command

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to run a Docker image (published in the Docker hub) in the Azure Devops pipeline and it's failing because it fails to find the image. There is no code example of start a command of Docker@2 task. I appreciate any help or hint.

Error

```
/usr/bin/docker start redfishmock
Error response from daemon: No such container: redfishmock
Error: failed to start containers: redfishmock
##[error]Error response from daemon: No such container: redfishmock
##[error]Error: failed to start containers: redfishmock
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
```

Pipeline yaml

```
trigger: none

resources:
  containers:
  - container: redfishmock
    image: dmtf/redfish-mockup-server:latest

jobs:
- job: RunTest
  workspace:
    clean: all
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - task: Docker@2
    displayName: start redfish mock
    inputs:
      command: start
      container: redfishmock
```